# (MV3 Chrome Extensions) How to forcefully keep a service worker alive?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, service-worker

Migrating my extension from MV2 has been a real pain for me. How do I prevent my extension SW from dying before a certain event (like onMessage or onStorageChanged) is triggered? this is the scenario:

1 - Send a message to contentScript from SW

2 - Wait for the contentScript to complete an operation

3 - contentScript sends a message back to SW when it's done

Unfortunately, the SW dies between steps 2 and 3. How can I prevent that?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66618136/

Answer (score 4):

Don't send separate messages, but use a single message cycle.

- background service worker:

  ```js
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {foo: 'bar'}, response => {
    // process the response
  });
  ```
- content script:

  ```js
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
    doSomethingAsynchronous(msg).then(sendResponse);
    return true; // keep the channel open
  });
  ```

This will keep the worker running for up to five minutes. If you need more than that or if you really want to send separate messages then open a new connection via chrome.runtime.connect ([documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#connect)) from your content script at the start of the cycle and repeat it every five minutes until the work is done.

Comment: For persistence via serviceWorker messaging see [this repo](https://github.com/guest271314/persistent-serviceworker).